# Environment variable in LXSession autostart file?

Tags: lxde

Anyone know how to use environment variables or something similar in an LXSession autostart file?  My initial attempts seem to have failed :-(.  I'm creating a Chromium kiosk noticeboard and need an easy way to configure the website and don't want to have users editing the LXSession autostart file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Could not make this work directly but the launching a shell script from within the autostart file does work and it can contain environment variables.  However remember to launch via a shell so...

```
# In .../autostart place this
@/bin/bash  /usr/bin/script_with_env_vars.sh
#
# Calling directly will not work
@/usr/bin/script_with_env_vars.sh - fails!!!
```

Comment: unfortunately a subprocess set variables only for itself and its children. It doesn't affect the parent environment.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is with .xinitrc. Notice if .xinitrc exists, its responsible to start the desktop environment (startlxde/startkde/...). I tried to just set TERM and exit and my XDE login just crashed.

```
#!/bin/bash
export TERM=linux
exec startlxde
```

Trying to run a child process to set the environment is futile as it happily changes its own environment then exit, leaving the parent process environment unchanged.